# List directory in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

Is there anyway to list the directory contents in javascript/ES6 ?

I am developing a website using react and the site has an image gallery. Now I want this gallery to be dynamic so I don't have to update the code everytime I want to add an image. I have the images stored on the server where I am hosting the webpage in a seperate directory for each gallery and every directory has a couple of images in it. My current solution is to hard-code every what images belongs to what gallery but there has to be a better solution.

I am using https://github.com/neptunian/react-photo-gallery if that matters. I also have access and can use a database to just store the filepaths but if there is another solution I'll rather use that to avoid having to create an API for adding images.

Comment: you can do it in server. so make an api call to server script which will list the files in particular directory and send it back as a response.

Comment: Pretty much what @error404 said. A simple server script if you've got php might look like `<?php print json_encode(scandir(getcwd()));?>`, this will include . and .. though (current and parent directory). Pretty simple and gives you the data in a usable format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

React is client-side, so the files are actually being read from your server. So, all you have to do is add an ajax call from the client, that the server responds to with the img src addresses. So something like:

```
componentDidMount() {
 $.ajax({ 
  method: "GET",
  url: "http://adsafasdf.com/imagecategory"
 }).then(function(response) { 
  this.setState({ imagesArray: JSON.parse(response) })
 });
}

render() {
  const images = this.state.imagesArray.map((object) => {
    return <img src={object.src} />;
  });

  return (
    <div>
     { images }
    </div>
  )
}
```

I may have a few errors there, but you should get the idea. And, imagecategory you should bring in from category that is clicked, at least I think that's how you're doing it. Like this, everything should be fully dynamic.

Comment: PS: componentDidMount may not be a good place to make that call, you may have to use a click handler function, or something along those lines. You basically just want the user to click on the category, load the category into the url, call an ajax function, then call setState on your new images, which will re-render the component and its children.

Comment: This answer and comments on OP is what I ended up using. As suggested I created an php script on the server that runs `scandir()` on a directory provided as GET request parametre and then returns result as JSON.

Answer (score 0):

You should prune the data prior to sending it over the wire. After that, you can map over your `Image` element whatever that may be called and render out the images accordingly. If you are in redux, and want the pictures stored in state, update the redux store, otherwise you can `setState` with the photos in an array and use `Array.map` to map over them in `JSX`